# Is it more efficient to create a dictionary in python using zip or a list comprehension?

Tags: python, optimization, dictionary, zip, list-comprehension

Lets say I want to set up a basic text encoding using a dictionary in python.

Two ways of doing this come to mind immediately - using zip, and using list comprehension.

```
characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ .,!;"
dict_a = dict((x, characters[x]) for x in xrange(0, 31))
dict_b = dict(zip(xrange(0, 31), characters))
```

Which of these is more efficient? (The real encoding is longer than 31, this is a toy example). Is the difference significant?

Alternatively, am I approaching this wrong and should be using something other than a dictionary? (I need to be able to go in both directions of encoding).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`enumerate` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) is probably the easiest way to create your `dict`:

```
dict_c = dict(enumerate(characters))
```

However, I'm not sure what that gives you that you can't do with the string.  The following seem equivalent to me:

```
>>> dict_c[3]
'D'
>>> characters[3]
'D'
```

Comment: The most significant benefit being the lack of the need to update the xrange parameters?

Comment: @Zxaos and clarity, IMO.  You could still do it using `xrange` and `len` for y our sequence, but this is much more succinct and clear.

Comment: Yes, it works with and string size. Plus, it's shorter, and probably written in C under the hood, so faster.

Comment: Hrm, I see what you mean about the string. What I was hoping for was a two-way one-to-one mapping, so that I could do dict_c[3] = a and then dict_c.some_method(a) = 3. That said, I suppose I could reverse the key-value pairs in the dictionary, use that for character lookup, then use the string for numeric lookup. Alternatively, I could add the inverse mappings to the same dictionary so one k-v pair is 0-a and another is a-0.

Comment: However, the best way to write a dict with integer keys that start at 0 is ... a `list`. It takes constant time to index too, without the need for hashing.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I might change the question so it isn't a special case then...